# GCC unexpected behaviour when selecting function overload in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, overloading

Consider the following example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

namespace nr {

  template <typename T>
  static inline std::string tostr(T const& v)
  {
    return std::to_string(v);
  }

}

namespace nr {
namespace logging {

  enum Level {
    kDebug,
    kInfo,
    kWarning,
    kError
  };


  template <typename T>
  static inline void log(std::string const& message, T const& v)
  {
    std::cout << message << nr::tostr(v) << "\n";
  }

}
}

namespace nr {

  static inline std::string tostr(nr::logging::Level level)
  {
    switch (level) {
      case nr::logging::kDebug:
        return "DEBUG";
      case nr::logging::kInfo:
        return "INFO";
      case nr::logging::kWarning:
        return "WARNING";
      case nr::logging::kError:
        return "ERROR";
      default:
        return "UNKNOWN_LEVEL";
    }
  }

}

int main()
{
  nr::logging::log("Hello", nr::logging::kInfo);
  nr::logging::log("Hello", nr::logging::kWarning);
}
```

This is the output compiled with GCC 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10

```
Hello1
Hello2
```

What I would expect it to output, and it does so on Windows with MSVC 2013:

```
HelloINFO
HelloWARNING
```

---

I have found ways to fix it, but I do not understand why there are different behaviours! As far as I understand it, the `nr::logging::log()` template is instantiated at the point the function is called for the first time.  At that very point, `nr::tostr(nr::logging::Level)` is already defined, thus it should select this function in `nr::logging::log()`.

Why is there a different behaviour depending on the order that the functions are declared in or whether they are in the global namespace or not?

Things to consider that puzzle me:

- Why does snippet #3 work as I expect it while snippet #2 does not? The only difference is that the functions are all in the same but their own namespace instead of the global namespace.
- In reply to @juanchopanza 's comment, if the function overload `nr::tostr(nr::logging::Level)` does not exist at the time `nr::log()` is called, why does snippet #3 do what I expect it to? The order is still the same (the function overload being declared after `nr::log()`)

---

- [#1 Original Code *](http://ideone.com/570ZwR)
- [#2 Put everything in `nr` namespace *](http://ideone.com/Zuzld0)
- [#3 Put everything in global namespace](http://ideone.com/Yhlafs)
- [#4 Declare `nr::tostr(nr::logging::Level)` before `nr::logging::log()`](http://ideone.com/0eGe5R)

*Snippets marked with * do NOT work as I expected it*

Comment: So your expectation is that `log` find a function that doesn't exist at the point it calls it? You shouldn't assume gcc is wrong here.

Comment: @juanchopanza As I mentioned in the question, I think `nr::log()` is instantiated at the time it is first called, thus the function overload `nr::tostr(nr::logging::Level)` exists. If that was **not** the case, why would snippet #3 work, where the order is the same but everything is in the global namespace? From your argument, it should still not be able to find the function. Please correct me if I am wrong about this. -- I'll rephrase the title.

Comment: Name lookup happens at the point of template definition. Only argument-dependent lookup is performed at the point of instantiation - but that's not applicable when `tostr` is called with a qualified name. Your snippet #3 is different in that it uses unqualified name, and so ADL kicks in. MSVC gets it all wrong because it notoriously doesn't implement two-phase name lookup - it looks up everything at the point of instantiation.